# What version of entity framework does .NET 4.5 have in it?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm upgrading to .NET 4.5 at work for some projects and I was using EF 5. Do I still need to reference EF 5 from all the projects?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework 5 is a separate API, not included with .NET 4.5 framework specifically (but VS2012 does include it). Preferably, you'd use NuGet to include and reference it in all your projects that require it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will still have to reference EF -- it's not baked into `System` or one of the core .NET assemblies.

However, if your project was pre-.NET 4.5, you were referencing EF 4.4, not really EF 5.  The version of the assembly is different than the version of EF for the 4.5 .NET Framework.  So you would want to make sure you upgrade your version of EF to the true EF5 which is supported on the .NET 4.5 Framework.

This [article](http://www.codevendor.com/news/when-entity-framework-5-ef5-is-not-entity-framework-5-ef5/) explains it pretty well.

Comment: The link in this answer is returning a 404.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Here seems to be an actual link to the article: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/when-entity-framework-5-ef5-is-not-entity-framework-5-ef5/